# Video with Optional Subtitles: Is there a suitable file format?

Tags: video, subtitle

I have a DVD with audio in another language, and optional subtitles in English. I would like to have a single file which includes the optional subtitles, but gives me the option whether to display it.

Assuming that the player is something like VLC (I also have 8Player and InFuse for the Apple TV), and assuming that I have a choice of ripping software, such as HandBrake, the question is:

**Is there a suitable container format for video with soft subtitles?**

I don’t know much about the various formats, other than it’s a bit of a jungle. From what I understand, MKV might be a suitable candidate, but I don’t know about MP4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MP4 as a container can contain subtitle streams as well as video and audio streams.

You can use ffmpeg to add subtitles: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/subtitle_options

Your player should allow you to choose the subtitles via the settings.

One thing to note based on your scenario - if the original subtitles are 'hard' encoded into the video then this will be an issue for you, as removing them will not be trivial. It may be ok for your purposes to simply have two sets of subtitles, one above the other, but obviously this does to always look great.